# android- navigation component Parcelable arguments not found on release variant

Tags: android, parcelable

i have a strange Error, I'm developing an app and I'm using `navigation component`, i need to pass Custom `Parcelable` objects to some fragments using `safeArgs`, actually the app works fine on debug builds, unfortunately when tried to launch the app on release mode the app throws a
`FATAL EXCEPTION`.
Models are in a separated module, do i need to add a specific config in this module?

this is an example of the models

```
@Parcelize
@Serializable
data class Article(
    val articleId: Int,
///
) : Parcelable
```

this is the stack Trace of exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ..., PID: 11381
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #101 in .....:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #101 in ...:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        at.... //
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #101 in ....:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #101 in ....:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #101 in ....:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception inflating ....:navigation/navigation line 168
       //....
E/AndroidRuntime:     at ...///
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ......app_models.Article
        at p4.o.a(NavType.java:181)
        at androidx.navigation.g.e(NavInflater.java:191)
        at androidx.navigation.g.g(NavInflater.java:155)
        at androidx.navigation.g.b(NavInflater.java:128)
        at androidx.navigation.g.b(NavInflater.java:141)
        at androidx.navigation.g.c(NavInflater.java:88)
            ... 42 more
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ....app_models.Article
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379)
        at p4.o.a(NavType.java:169)
            ... 47 more
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "....app_models.Article" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~Frr3Sf0kFWBoEFseLYT-jQ==/....-BW1tOT8d2hUlYJyi1fggPw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~Frr3Sf0kFWBoEFseLYT-jQ==/...-BW1tOT8d2hUlYJyi1fggPw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
```

Nb: i've replaced the package names with 3 dots
thank you

Comment: You need to add Proguard configuration to keep the names of your classes that are annotated with `@Parcelize` or implement `Parcelable` or so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add at least the following to your Proguard config:

```
-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable
```

Although it can also make sense to make sure the CREATOR field is kept

```
-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```